# spring resource mapping not working

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

currently i am working in a spring project. when i try to access style sheet from resource folder a resource not found error is occurring. i mapped the resource folder using mvc:resource mapping.here is my code:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resourcs/" />
```

in my jsp page :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="<c:url value='/resources/css/login.css'/>">
```

Dispatcher Servlet:

```
    <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd ">
```

if you need more specific code from my project, please let me know.

Comment: There might be a typo: `resourcs` (missing `e`). If that's not the cause of your issue, set "org.springframework" logs to DEBUG, launch your page again and post the logs

Comment: you are right i fixed the issue but an error is displaying in eclipse console and a 500 error in browser error cause in console is javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getHeader(Ljava/lang/‌​String;)Ljava/lang/S‌​tr

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="<c:url value='/css/login.css'/>">` remove `/resource` from `href`

Answer (score 0):

Check the resources folder name here `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resourcs/" />`

and the one here `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="<c:url value='/resources/css/login.css'/>">`

Hope it solves the issue!

Comment: finally i landed in this error     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getHeader(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; how can i fix this? can you help me.

Comment: I'm having same error, but I'm doing JAXB. I think you should check the xsd mappings in spring configuration file

Comment: i updated my question with my dispatcher servlet please check it

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a spelling mistake. It should look like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
```

Let me know if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: finally i landed in this error     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getHeader(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; how can i fix this? can you help me.

Comment: Please post the whole exception text. I can't tell anything from just this one line. It could be due to a spelling mistake or due to a mismatch between compile time and runtime environments or a configuration issue.

Comment: here it is the complete one

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getHeader(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.checkNotModified(ServletWebRequest.java:187)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:240)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)

Comment: at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Comment: Ok. Start checking from your dispatcher servlet. There may be a mismatch there. Also, clean the project and then check to see if there are jars that shouldn't be there or may be incompatible with your version of Spring. Remove those jars.

Comment: i updated my question with my dispatcher servlet please check it

Answer (score 0):

finally i cleared it my self.
its just a version problem not a conflict. i changed my spring version from 4.2.1 release to 4.2.2. it seems a bug in the version...

Thank you